# Can we or Should we build a public health records be kept on the bitcoin network?

Tags: network

Can/Should we public health records be kept on the bitcoin network?
If your answer no, would love to know why?

If your answer is yes, what do you think the most efficient way to build such a ledger?
Can it be cheap to mint (if the time of minting the record takes a while?)
Could it be done with ordinals?

Answer (score 3):

No. It’s not clear to me why putting medical records on the Bitcoin blockchain would be desirable in any way. Firstly, it’s expensive to write to Bitcoin blockspace. Secondly, the data is immutable, and therefore any updates to the data would require writing even more data to the blockchain. Thirdly, all data in the Bitcoin blockchain is public. Clearly, the data should not be written in clear-text, since we’re talking about sensitive health records. Yet, even if it’s encrypted, who would you encrypt it to? If you encrypt it symmetrically with a password, nothing stops a recipient from forwarding the information or password once they learn it, which is much worse protection than the current. If you asymmetrically encrypt it to specific recipients, at least you’d need to share tweaks on the blockchain to add more readers, and either way it’s just useful to a small number of recipients. Especially if a lot of people were using the Bitcoin blockchain for this purpose, it would quickly overwhelm the Bitcoin blockchain’s data capacity.

It’s not clear to me what benefit you expect from putting health records on the Bitcoin blockchain, but I am convinced that you would be able to achieve that same benefit with a less inefficient and more suitable technology.

Comment: I don’t know if you or anyone else would agree with my theory.

Comment: Well, clearly I don’t agree, I think it’s a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry my response was cut short somehow…. 

Philosophically health and wealth are connected.  You’re nothing with out your health. And a trustless health system is just dying to be created.  I don’t know if you or anyone else would agree with my theory., but Offering a dynamic immutable health record solution perhaps using layer tows? would be a great service to any economy as if my research is correct, it would be deflationary for the economy (in the right places) and would bring adoption; slow ; but never the less a massive wave of adoption to the bitcoin network. Thoughts ?

Comment: I don’t see how building a “trustless health system” is helped by or predicated on putting health records on the Bitcoin blockchain. I simply don’t see how that solves any interesting problem for you.

Comment: Perhaps this idea might sound counter intuitive at this point in time.

Comment: Could you elaborate what benefit you expect from health records on the blockchain? What are you trying to achieve? Auditability, transparency, completeness, accessibility?